# use loco translate for translating the buddyboss theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, translation, translate

i've activted the loco translate plugin on wordpress but i keep geting this error when i try to translate a string form the buddyboss theme english to arabic
(Error: Attention Required! | Cloudflare. Check console output for debugging information) any idea why is this happing? please help , and thanks

Comment: Did you check console?

Comment: yes it's showing me this message (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ())

Comment: That's your problem. The server is rejecting the request

Comment: any idea how to solve it

Comment: Check htaccess and other permissions in your apache config

Answer (score 0):

Use [Automatic Translate Addon For Loco Translate][1]

[1]: https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-translator-addon-for-loco-translate/ along with loco translator plugin. it translate your website within few minutes.